# How to find which Finalizer is time consuming

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, finalizer, finalize

I am working on an application whose purpose is to compute reports has fast as possible.

My application uses a big amount of memory; more than 100 Go.

Since our last release, I notice a big performance slowdown. My investigation shows that, during the computation, I get many garbage collection between 40 and 60 seconds!!!
*(JMC tells me that they are **SerialOld** but I don't know what it exactly means)* and, of course, when the JVM is garbage collecting, the application is absolutely freezed

I am now investigating the origin of these garbage collections... and this is a very hard work.

I suspect that, if these garbage collections are so long, it is because they are spending many times in `finalize` functions *(I know that, among all the libraries we integrate from other teams, some of them uses finalizers)*

However, I don't know how to confrim (or not) this hypothesis; How to find which finalizer is time consuming.

I am looking for a good tool or even a good methodology

> Here is data collected via JVisualVM
>   [image: Taken from JVisualVM's "Tracer" tab]
>
> As you can see, I always have many "Pending Finalizers" when I have a
>   log Old Garbage
>
> What is surprising is that when I am using JVisualVM, the above graph
>   scrolls regularly from right to left. When the Old Garbage is
>   triggered, the scrolling stops (until here, it looks normal, this is
>   end-of-world). However, when the scrolling suddenly restart, it does
>   not from the end of Old Garbage but from the end of Pending Serializer
>
> This lets me think that the finalizers were blocking the JVM
>
> Does anyone has an explaination for this?

Thank you very much
Philippe

Comment: `finalize` methods are *not* executed during garbage collections.

Comment: sure? Even for "SerializeOld" garbage collection?
Thanks for your answer

Comment: Absolutely. No Java code is run during non-concurrent GC phases. GC only *discovers* finalizable objects and adds them to a queue. This queue is later processed by [`Finalizer`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8b04ee324a1a/src/share/classes/java/lang/ref/Finalizer.java#l186) Java thread which runs along with other Java threads.

Comment: OK, clear. Thanks again. "This queue is later processed by Finalizer Java thread" Does this means they are run sequentially? How many "Finalizer Java thread" does the JVM has? Just one? Is the number of Finalizer threads customizable via a JVM parameter? (these questions are for my own culture but I don't think they relate to my original issue)

Comment: Yes, there is only one Finalizer thread which runs all finalizers sequentially.

Comment: Anything taking that long can be picked up by taking a thread dump while this is happening. Have a look at the stack trace of the Finalizer thread, my guess is it's closing a socket which is timing out.

Comment: finalize methods can be a problem like this if they synchronize on something also used by other code (e.g. database connection).  The single finalizer thread may become a bottleneck.  Better not to do anything in finalize if you can.

Comment: Check if you're closing resources properly. Finalizers gets sometimes used as a last resort ensuring a resource gets eventually closed. If you close them yourself, the delay gets better distributed in time and also distributed across threads. Moreover, fewer resources are needed and closing them might be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

> My application uses a big amount of memory; more than 100 Go.
>
> JMC tells me that they are SerialOld but I don't know what it exactly means

If you are using the serial collector for a 100GB heap then long pauses are to be expected because the serial collector is single-threaded and one core can only only chomp through so much memory per unit of time.

Simply choosing any one of the multi-threaded collectors should yield lower pause times.

> However, I don't know how to confrim (or not) this hypothesis; How to find which finalizer is time consuming.

Generally: Gather more data. For GC-related things you need to enabled GC logging, for time spent in java code (be it your application or 3rd party libraries) you need a profiler.

Comment: FYI, I am using the G1GC garbage collector

Comment: "If you are using the serial collector" 1) What do you mean by Serial Collector? 2) Do you mean that I can use another one? How?

Comment: Your question said *SerialOld*, that's mutually exclusive with G1GC. *How?* there are many other answers on stack overflow covering that and so does oracle's garbage collector documentation.

Comment: SerialOld != G1GC, you can't be using both.

Comment: However, when looking at the problematic garbadge collection (those whose duration is around 40-60 seconds), JMC mark them as "SerialOld". And for sure I am using G1GC

Comment: well, they might be last ditch GCs. A GC log would be more informative than.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do to investigate your finalizer theory.

1. Start the JVM using your favorite Java profiler.
2. Leave it running for long enough to get a full heap.
3. Start the profiler.
4. Trigger garbage collection.
5. Stop profiler.

Now you can use the profiler information to figure out which (if any) `finalize` methods are using a large amount of time.

---

However, I suspect that the real problem will be a memory leak, and that your JVM is getting to the point where the heap is filling up with unreclaimable objects.  That could explain the frequent "SerialOld" garbage collections.

Alternatively, this could just be a big heap problem.  100Gb is ... big.